# Program still passes through "else" statement even if the "if" condition has been met

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I encountered a weird problem that has been hindering me from proceeding with my program. Below, I wrote a WHILE statement that loops through a block of codes until the variable `scount` is no longer greater than 0.

```
scount = 42 # this is a sample data only
half = scount / 2     
while scount > 0:
    if half > 0:
        scount -= half
        half -= half
    else:
        scount = 0
```

On the first loop, the program will see that the variable `half` is greater than 0. Then, `half` will halve the `scount` and set itself into 0. On the second loop, the program will find out that `half` is no longer greater than 0, so the program will move to the ELSE statement and set `scount` to 0. This will end the WHILE statement's looping and we have all the values of the variables 0. The problem  here is that after the program sets `half` to 0, it jumps straight to the ELSE statement and sets `scount` to 0. Why is that?

Comment: It doesn't jump "straight" to the `else`statement. After half reaches 0, it will start from the top of the `while loop` again and then go to the `else` statement.

Comment: `half -= half` -> after your first while iteration half = 0. Did you mean `half = scount / 2`?

Comment: @JaxTeller Okay this is very embarrassing. The issue why after the IF condition moves to the Else condition after it has been met is because of the indentation of the print. I set the print line to printout the result on the same indentation of the WHILE statement. The print will only get the last loop which is 0. This means I made a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written out the what your program is doing, hopefully this helps.

```
loop 1:
 scount = 42
 half = 21

 half > 0, so
   scount = 21
   half = 0

loop 2:
  scount = 21
  half = 0

  half < 0, so
    scount = 0

stop, scount is not > 0
```

Your program only loops twice, and half is only greater than 0 on the first loop (where you then set it to 0). Therefore any subsequent loops will never execute the if statement code, as half is not greater than 0. It then runs the else code, setting scound to 0 which means the loop condition is no longer true, and it ends.

Comment: Okay this is very embarrassing. The issue why after the IF condition moves to the Else condition after it has been met is because of the indentation of the print. I set the print line to printout the result on the same indentation of the WHILE statement. The print will only get the last loop which is 0. This means I made a wrong assumption.

Comment: All good, It's all a learning experience. Hope it all works out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, it will run e.g. like that:

```
scount = 2
half = 1
while loop (true)
  if scount>0 (true)
    scount = 2-1 = 1
    half = 1-1 = 0
while loop (true)
  if half>0 (false)
    scount = 0
while loop (false)
```

So it doesn't jump straight, only under next, last iteration of while loop you enters to the else statement

Comment: Okay this is very embarrassing. The issue why after the IF condition moves to the Else condition after it has been met is because of the indentation of the print. I set the print line to printout the result on the same indentation of the WHILE statement. The print will only get the last loop which is 0. This means I made a wrong assumption.

Answer (score 0):

The program runs exactly as it should

Put some print statements to understand:

```
scount = 42 # this is a sample data only
half = scount / 2
loop_count=0
while scount > 0:
    loop_count += 1
    print(loop_count)
    print('Outside IF-ELSE: scount is ',scount)
    print('Outside IF-ELSE: half is ',half)
    print()
    if half > 0:
        scount -= half
        half -= half
        print('inside \'if\' block scount is', scount)
        print('inside \'if\' block half is', half)
        print()
    else:
        scount = 0
        print('inside \'else\' block scount is', scount)
        print('inside \'else\' block half is', half)
        print()
```

The output will be:

```
1
Outside IF-ELSE: scount is  42
Outside IF-ELSE: half is  21.0

inside 'if' block scount is 21.0
inside 'if' block half is 0.0

2
Outside IF-ELSE: scount is  21.0
Outside IF-ELSE: half is  0.0

inside 'else' block scount is 0
inside 'else' block half is 0.0
```

In the first loop as half is 21 program control goes inside the 'if' block and its value changes to 0, it does not enter else loop

In the second loop as half is set to 0 it can't go inside the 'if' block because half has to be >0, which it is not, so it jumps directly to the 'else' block.

Now inside 'else' block scount is also set to 0 so it cant enter while loop anymore terminating the program.

Hope you got some clarity!

Comment: Okay this is very embarrassing. The issue why after the IF condition moves to the Else condition after it has been met is because of the indentation of the print. I set the print line to printout the result on the same indentation of the WHILE statement. The print will only get the last loop which is 0. This means I made a wrong assumption.

Comment: Well, indentation in python can be irritating sometimes and lead to such confusion. Hope you got the reqd clarification to your problem.